# My AWS SSL Certificate is not appearing in Elastic Beanstalk's console

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I've created a new SSL Certificate using AWS's service for a subdomain that points to an Elastic Beanstalk instance. It appears in the Certificate Manager correctly...

[image]

but it doesn't appear in the EB instance's Load Balancer dropdown...

[image]

According to the documentation ([Configuring Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Load Balancer to Terminate HTTPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html)), all I need to do is "choose your certificate from the SSL certificate ID drop down menu", but it's not there.

I've tried to add the SSL certificate through a .config file using CLI and I got the following error:

> ERROR: Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-upxkf5kr8b-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'  Reason: null
>       ERROR: Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-u-AWSEBLoa-xxx failed Reason: Server Certificate not found for the key: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:xxx:certificate/xxxx

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was rather silly. A little gotcha: I didn't notice that I'd changed my region when I created the SSL Certificate, so the ELB and the certificate regions didn't match.

I deleted the cert, switched region to match my ELB instance, and then requested a new one. Worked as expected! Doh.

Comment: Django. Thank you for posting the solution. I have ran into this gotcha several times.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with this stupid region auto-switch for 2 hours!

Comment: Turned out to be the same problem for me. This is weird as the original certificate worked in _all_ regions for CloudFront.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The LetsEncrypt cert I imported doesn't show up, but I see nowhere to set the region.

Comment: @Half_Duplex Top right corner on every page